# Is there an adjective to describe one's feeling when they are sad but smiling or laughing?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

> He might be smiling, but he's actually __. He just doesn't show it.

I don't think sad fits there. It doesn't sound good to me. What is the appropriate adjective to fill the gap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sad or any synonym of sad is appropriate. Angry or any synonym of angry would also be appropriate. Basically, any emotion that is not expressed by smiling is appropriate. All of the following would work: sad, angry, frustrated, disappointed, bored.

Comment: Thank you. What about suffering? He's actually suffering. Is that appropriate as well?

Comment: Yes, suffering would be appropriate. I think you’ve got it!